# redux - how to create a generic reducer?

Tags: redux, react-redux, reducers

In react-redux, I'm trying to create a generic reducer, meaning a reducer with common logic that writes (with that logic) each time to a different section in the store.

I read [Reusing Reducer Logic](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/reusing-reducer-logic) over and over, I just can't wrap my head around it. Let's say I have this state:

`{
     a: { b: { c: {...} } } },
     d: { c: {...} }
}`

`a` and `d` are two reducers combined with `combineReducers()` to create the store. I want section `c` to be managed with common logic. I wrote the reducer logic for `c`, I wrapped it to create a higher-order reducer with a name.

How do I create the `a` reducer with the `c` reducer with reference to its location (and also `d` accordingly)? Maybe in other words, how do I create a reducer with a "store address", managing his slice of the state, agnostic to where it is?

I sure hope someone understands me, I'm new to redux and react.

Comment: wait.. so you have state `a.b.c` and `d.c`. same logic but different actual state?

Comment: I think the complexity here is created by nested state, and then further by nested and similar state. the conventional wisdom is to store state as flat as possible, then "compose" states together where needed

Comment: Redux is pretty boilerplate-heavy. As @azium pointed out, the state is supposed to be relatively flat. Maybe the nesting in your state requires you to write too much repetitive code that you feel should be reused? We could give an actual answer if you describe the logic that is common in the `c` reducer. Maybe there's a better way than watering down the simplicity of reducers with "inheritance" or whatever pattern you might have in mind :)

Comment: @timotgl [redux is only boilerplate heavy if you set it up that way](https://medium.com/@benevolentNinja/minimal-redux-setup-e6a10fcbcb68). you can setup a meaningful redux setup with < 15 lines if you wanted

Comment: Sure, but you start repeating yourself when there's multiple reducers (properly) handling ajax requests and things like that. Keeping things very DRY is often difficult with Redux without ruining the simplicity by adding abstractions on top of it.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. I'll share the actual case: `c` is data managed by a reducer called `filter`. It's a map of `filter_field` to `value` and I want to attach that ability to have a `filter` section at various locations in the store, but its structure and logic are always the same, just the data is different and updated separately - as a higher order reducer, I supposed. That is the actual case I'm trying to implement.

Comment: You need to edit the title of this post. It says how to create a generic reducer, but based on the back and forth here, that's not what you want.

Comment: Sorry @Daniel, that is what I want. A piece of generic code that handle a slice of the state, agnostic to where it is in the store.

Comment: @nadavelyashiv, I can provide you with a piece of generic `reducer` code if that will meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Reducer are now simple function and can be reuse somewhere else

```
const getData = (state, action) => {
    return {...state, data: state.data.concat(action.payload)};
};

const removeLast = (state) => {
    return {...state, data: state.data.filter(x=>x !== state.data[state.data.length-1])};
}
```

Action type and reducer function are now declared in an array

```
const actions = [
    {type: 'GET_DATA', reducer: getData},
    {type: 'REMOVE_LAST', reducer: removeLast}
];
```

Initial state for the reducer

```
const initialState = {
    data: []
}
```

actionGenerators creates an unique Id using Symbol and assign that Id to actions and reducer function.

```
const actionGenerators = (actions) => {
    return actions.reduce((a,c)=>{
        const id = Symbol(c.type);   
        a.actions = {...a.actions, [c.type]: id};
        a.reducer = a.reducer ? a.reducer.concat({id, reducer: c.reducer}) : [{id, reducer: c.reducer}];
        return a;
    },{});
}
```

reducerGenerators is a generic reducer creator.

```
const reducerGenerators = (initialState, reducer) => {
    return (state = initialState, action) => {
        const found = reducer.find(x=>x.id === action.type);
        return found ? found.reducer(state, action) : state;
    }
}
```

Usage

```
const actionsReducerCreator = actionGenerators(actions);
const store = createStore(reducerGenerators(initialState, actionsReducerCreator.reducer));
const {GET_DATA} = actionsReducerCreator.actions;
store.dispatch({type: GET_DATA});
```

Checkout my github project where I have a working todo application utilizing this implementation.

[Redux-Reducer-Generator](https://github.com/Thuthinh/Redux-Reducer-Generator)